# What is definition of "viewport" on CSS?

Tags: css, viewport

I want to do responsive design for my website. I am confused about adding `@media` and `@import` in CSS.

What is the definition of "viewport" in CSS? How to measure the viewpoint of smartphones and iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Read this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: The definition can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport), but based on your introduction I strongly suspect that is not the answer you're *really* looking for. If you have a specific problem with CSS, post your code and describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Viewport** is browser area visible to user or you can say window visible to user.

If you want to target media queries, go through [mydevice.io](http://mydevice.io/). For mobiles and tables use device width to write the media query.

But I will prefer to use write media queries using either min-width or max-width. Use breakpoints.

`@import` is to import the css

`@media` is to write media queries not only for responsive but you can write print media queries and lot more

Answer (score 1):

If your using Chrome u can:

right click -> inspect -> and toggle device mode(Ctrl+Shift+M)

Or press F12.

Then the width and height will be displayed, you can also change what deavice you would like to view as.

This site have good information. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

I have read in books that it's better to design for mobile devices and then change
if a desktop user enters your website. I think it loads faster that way.

**NOTE**

I can't comment otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: Probably better to design with a focus on site users, as opposed to mobile or desktop devices. If the majority of visitors are on a desktop browser, why go mobile first? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Well I will go after what I read in books or good sites like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp.                Always Design for Mobile First
Mobile First means designing for mobile before designing for desktop or any other device (This will make the page display faster on smaller devices).

This means that we must make some changes in our CSS.

Instead of changing styles when the width gets smaller than 768px, we should change the design when the width gets larger than 768px. This will make our design Mobile First:

Answer (score 1):

This is a detailed explanation of what you wanted to know.
[The Viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

If you are using chrome then follow the following steps to get the viewport of any device

Press F12 > then click on toggle device mode (its on the top right corner of the window that will appear after pressing F12) > from the drop down menu select the desired device then you can get your viewport's width and height